# Is there a limit on the length or nesting of Tcl/Tk widget pathnames?

Tags: tcl, limit, tk-toolkit, pathname

Is there a limit on the length or nesting of Tcl/Tk widget pathnames?

For example:

```
ttk::button .a.b.c -text "Hello World"
pack .a.b.c
```

creates button `.a.b.c` inside container `.a.b` which is inside `.a`, etc. Is there a limit to the identifier names and nesting level? For example if i rewrote it thus:

```
ttk::button .extralonga.extralongb.extralongc -text "Hello World"
pack .extralonga.extralongb.extralongc
```

How long can i go before hitting problems?

Comment: Tk/TTk developers don't like to introduce artifical limits, so no chance to get "name too long" / "nesting too deep" as an error. You get slowdown for deep nesting (platform-dependent and configuration-dependent, so you have to test), and full wigdet pathnames get copied for each event which has a binding (thus a megabyte-long name is not a good idea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tk itself imposes no such limits at all (though you could have problems if you end up using very large amounts of memory).

The underlying graphics layer might impose limits, I suppose, but I've never encountered them. (Note that from the perspective of that layer, it is only the path *within a toplevel* that counts.) I guess it's more likely that you'll create an unworkable mess and impractical GUI long before you hit any limits that exist; I tend to try to keep the level of nesting fairly small; using `grid` rather than `pack` helps in this, as does making interaction widgets direct children of the toplevel and using the `-in` option to the geometry managers to set things up right. In fact, I think the only thing that *must* be correct in terms of parent/child relationships with widgets is where you need the clipping; in Tk, children are clipped by their parents. (This matters if you're using a `text` or `canvas` to do different types of scrollable areas, or — IIRC — when using `ttk::notebook` to overlay several widgets on the one area.)

**Summary:** Worry about other problems first, OK?